# JacksonConverterFactory in Retrofit.Builder()

Tags: android, retrofit2

When using Gson for the Retrofit Builder I use:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(CustomAPI.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

How to add a JacksonConverterFactory to a Retrofit Builder?

Using

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
```

as Gradle Dependencies

On the internet I can get the class for the factory, but this must be imported somehow, as in all the tutorials they use Gson. The reason I need Jackson is because the models provided by the company make use of Jackson formatters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's possible to achieve that using this code snippet

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(WeCityAPI.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

and retrofit2 as dependency?

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
```

Comment: He asked for Jackson Convertor not GSON

Comment: @kshitijjain oops, didn't update answer, saved original code instead

Comment: Yup, Now its fine. Just have to use JacksonConverterFactory instead of GsonConverterFactory.